# Add text at the cursor (not at end of line) after catching EVT_KEY_DOWN

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I've written the following function which is triggered at each key down event in a text box. The idea is that it lets the user enter special characters (accented vowels for a Spanish verb conjugation testing app). It works perfectly when the cursor is at the end of the entered text, but if the user tries to go back and edit a letter in the middle of the control the special character still appears at the end. I know that this is because I'm using `AppendText` but I can't see anything like `InsertText` to insert text at a different insertion point. What is the right way to do this?

```
def SpecialChars(self, e):
    vowels = {65: 225, 69: 233, 73: 237, 79: 243, 85: 250}
    key = e.GetUniChar()
    if self.last_key_down == 'accent' and key in vowels.keys():
        self.answer_txt.AppendText(unichr(vowels[key]))
        self.last_key_down = 'none'
    elif key == 39:
        self.last_key_down = 'accent'        
    else:
        self.last_key_down = 'none'
        e.Skip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. `TextCtrl.WriteText()` does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
self.answer_txt.SetInsertionPoint(3)
self.answer_txt.Replace(3,3,"a")
```

Comment: I was thinking I'd have to use `SetInsertionPoint` but `WriteText` does what I need. Don't know how I missed it before asking this question.